# Nginx Ingress Controller randomly 404's - possibly not recognizing the correct certificate on every request?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to implement an endpoint through nginx ingress on kubernetes. The same configuration seems to work on another controller deployment in the same cluster, but here I'm getting very random 404 responses mixed in with the expected response.

Configuration for ingress-nginx-controller deployment, modified from the helm chart:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: Internal 
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.44.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.44.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: "k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0@sha256:3dd0fac48073beaca2d67a78c746c7593f9c575168a17139a9955a82c63c4b9a"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
            -  --default-ssl-certificate=kube-system/nginx-certificates ##custom by environment, must be created
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
                drop:
                - ALL
                add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
            - name: GODEBUG
              value: x509ignoreCN=0
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
```

The ingress configuration (service names/endpoints are changed for the sake of this post):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-request-buffering: "off"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: test-endpoint-svc
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-http-version: "1.1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-request-buffering: "off"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "False"
  labels:
    app: test-endpoint
  name: test-endpoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: test-endpoint-svc
    servicePort: 443
  rules:
  - host: test.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test-endpoint-svc
          servicePort: 443
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.internal
    secretName: nginx-certificates
```

And here's an example working output of `curl -k -vvv -u <user>:<password> https://test.internal`

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://test.internal/
*   Trying <correct ip>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to test.internal (<correct ip>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=test.internal; O=test.internal
*  start date: Mar  4 00:53:27 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Mar  4 00:53:27 2022 GMT
*  issuer: CN=test.internal; O=test.internal
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* Server auth using Basic with user '<user>'
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55a3643114c0)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: test.internal
> Authorization: Basic <password>
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Thu, 04 Mar 2021 01:05:43 GMT
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 533
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
<expected response>
```

Trying the same curl call half a second later:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://test.internal/
*   Trying <correct ip>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to test.internal (<correct ip>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  start date: Feb  5 20:51:55 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Feb  5 20:51:55 2022 GMT
*  issuer: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* Server auth using Basic with user <user>
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x560637cb34c0)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: test.internal
> Authorization: Basic <password>
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< HTTP/2 404 
< date: Thu, 04 Mar 2021 01:05:44 GMT
< content-type: text/html
< content-length: 146
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
< 
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* Connection #0 to host test.internal left intact
```

I've tried various changes to the ingress annotations, adding/removing the default host, and adding/removing the `GODEBUG` environment variable from the controller. There doesn't seem to be a pattern in when these calls succeed vs. 404, and I'm hesitant to dive into turning on 404 logs, as a custom template is needed (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4856).
The `nginx-certificates` secret is present in both `kube-system` & `default` namespaces, and was generated with openssl.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a React app, which was deployed using Kubernetes. From my experience, 404 page shows up - the fact that some response is returned - means deployment is working.

In my case whenever, I got 404, there was issue with the front end code. So, you should check your front end - specifically, the routing config.

Hopefully, this should give you some direction.